# Can limescale actually "etch" glass?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, minerals

There are lots of articles on the internet about limescale "etching" glass due to the porous nature of glass. However, as I understand it, limescale is just calcium carbonate so can it actually cause permanent damage to the glass (or any other material)? Or is it just the case that it can be difficult to clean as the limescale is "embedded" rather than the glass actually being "etched"?

Comment: It may be that anything getting into the pores creates the same effect as etching, increasing opacity to light.  Calcium carbonate can be removed with vinegar.

Comment: Glass is hardly porous. I have a feeling you're reading wrong kind of articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcium carbonate, $\ce{CaCO3}$ is alkaline, and can, *slowly*, combine with the silica in glass. Consider that window (soda-lime) glass is *made* from lime, $\ce{CaO}$, derived from $\ce{CaCO3}$, as well as silica and other oxides, and that silica is also slightly soluble in water ([cactus](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25115104/) and [maize](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ie2003768) contain silica phytoliths, derived from dissolved silica from the soil, for example).

Over a long period of time, the surface of the glass combines with $\ce{CaCO3}$, giving it a "frosted", translucent, appearance. Removing that surface coating is difficult, and, with [tempered glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempered_glass), perhaps impossible, because removing the thin surface of tempered glass can cause it to shatter. Acid cleaners can only remove the thinnest, newly-deposited, surface layer of lime.

Similarly, a glass bottle used for storing sodium hydroxide, $\ce{NaOH}$, becomes etched in a fairly short time. It's commonly found that $\ce{NaOH}$ reagent bottle have the ground-glass stopper permanently fused in place.

[[image: <span class=]$\ce{NaOH}$ Bottle" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4UnL.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, just the answer I was looking for! Out of interest, and I appreciate this is depedent on the circumstance, roughly how slowly is slowly?

Comment: From *personal* experience, a week's lime buildup on glass (and porcelain, which is glass-glazed) in our location, with fairly soft water, can be removed with gentle washing, and after a month, an acid cleaner is needed. *Mileage may vary...*